# What does this sentence mean "He has miles of jogging and a teleconference behind him"?

Tags: meaning

What does this sentence mean

> He has miles of jogging and a teleconference behind him

I don't know if it means that he hasn't done those things yet or if they are already done. Or something else.

Comment: This is the entire paragraph for more context. "CEOs often boast of heroic sleep patterns. Business journalists who shadow CEOs for a couple of days learn to rest up ahead of time. Breakfast is at 6 a.m. The reporter arrives with baggy eyes and wet hair. The CEO has miles of jogging and a teleconference to Eastern Europe behind him." It's from a piece of news about CEOs who don't sleep much but are very successful

Answer (score 1):

Some more context would be useful to give a complete answer on the precise nuance of the statement. But it is based on `behind him`, a figurative prepositional phrase meaning 'in the past', 'completed actions', 'events that have finished', etc. It means that he has already done miles of jogging and also did a teleconference. This is a rather bizarre combination of actions to place together in one sentence, but I'm guessing this is intended to be comical.  Here's another example:

> I have two exams **behind me** but one still **ahead of me**.
> (= I have completed two exams but there is one I have not yet done)